# Simple UIStackView breaks constraints

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a `UIStackView` inside a `UIViewRepresentable` but I am unable to get it working without constraint errors.

This is the error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000028edf40 h=--& v=--& benjamin_ios.ConversationChatViewWithSendMessage:0x7fef7323a610.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002893c00 UIView:0x7fef7322a3d0.height == 100   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002891d10 V:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7fef7320c450]   (active, names: '|':benjamin_ios.ConversationChatViewWithSendMessage:0x7fef7323a610 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002891c70 UIStackView:0x7fef7320c450.bottom == benjamin_ios.ConversationChatViewWithSendMessage:0x7fef7323a610.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028e6170 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fef7320c450.top == UIView:0x7fef73229830.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028e4050 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIView:0x7fef7322a3d0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fef7320c450 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028ecc30 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIView:0x7fef73229830]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fef7322a3d0]   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002893c00 UIView:0x7fef7322a3d0.height == 100   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

This is the code:

```
struct ConversationChatMessagesWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let view = ConversationChatViewWithSendMessage()

    func makeUIView(context _: Context) -> ConversationChatViewWithSendMessage {
        view
    }

    func updateUIView(
        _: ConversationChatViewWithSendMessage,
        context _: Context
    ) {}
}


class ConversationChatViewWithSendMessage: UIView {
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder _: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not used")
    }

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        backgroundColor = .red

        let otherView = UIView()

        otherView.backgroundColor = .blue
        otherView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let otherView2 = UIView()

        otherView2.backgroundColor = .brown
        otherView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [otherView, otherView2])

        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.distribution = .fill
        stack.alignment = .fill

        addSubview(stack)

        stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        otherView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }
}
```

This is what I want to achieve (The display actually is what I want but I want to get rid of the constraint errors):

[image]

Comment: My guess is since you've hard coded otherView2's height to be 100 whenever the ConversationChatViewWithSendMessage's height is below 100 you'll get the constraint error, other than that everything looks good. Maybe try setting up a proportional height relation between otherView and otherView2 so it works for all sizes...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to give all the constraints I created the defaultHigh priority. This has to do something with SwiftUI porting to UIKit since the code just works fine in plain UIKit.